# struct element manipulation (matlab)

Tags: matlab

I first loaded files from folder,  and then trying to excess them individually. Code looks like below;

```
pathname = uigetdir(pwd, 'Select a folder');
training_Sample= dir(fullfile(pathname, '*.wav'));
n_trainingSamples=length(training_Sample);

for i=1:n_trainingSamples
    [signal fs]=wavread(training_Sample(i,1).name);
    figure(i);
plot(signal);    

end
```

The Erroro message is:
Error using wavread (line 67)
Invalid Wave File. Reason: Cannot open file.

Error in folder_ (line 22)
       [signal fs]=wavread(training_Sample(i,1).name);

Comment: The error message is telling you all you need to know - check the input to the wavread -> i.e. `training_Sample(i,1).name`

Answer (score 0):

You only use the name, but maybe are not in the correct path.
just add as line 2:

```
cd(pathname)
```

or replace your waveread line with this:

```
[signal fs]=wavread(fullfile(pathname,training_Sample(i,1).name));
```

Comment: A much better solution is to use `fullfile` to generate the input to the `wavread` function

Comment: matlabgui : Thank you I corrected it in the answer
RajanSapkota: Concider marking the answer as correct.